# Including javascript file along with ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a dropdown that runs `AJAX` each time an option is selected. The ajax call returns `HTML` markup (buttons and text boxes) and a script tag, which the HTML(buttons) uses to submit to a database via ajax.

```
<html>
<head>........</head>
<body>........</body>
<select class="chooseOption">
...
...
</select>
<div class="ajaxResult">
<!-- after successful ajax -->
<!-- HTML Markup here -->
<!-- I'm having to include main.js here again so that HTML matkup can use AJAX -->
</div>
 ....
 ....
 ....
<footer> //include main.js </footer>
```

This arrangement seems to work *fine* only that, there's an exponential call to `main.js` each time an option is selected.

Doing something like this(below) doesn't seem to work, I'm guessing because `AJAX` is injected into the page and isn't aware of what scripts that are already available on the page?

```
<script>
var len = $('script').filter(function () {
    return ($(this).attr('src') == 'main.js');
}).length;

//if there are no scripts that match, the load it
if (len === 0) {
    var url = "main.js";
    $.getScript(url);
}
</script>
```

Is there a simple way around this? To make sure that main.js works across all AJAX requests without having to include it with each request?

### Sample main.js content.

Ajax snippet that populates the HTML Markup (buttons and textboxes)

```
    $("#students").on("change", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var supervise = this.value;
    var faculty = $("#faculty").val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'URL',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:
        {
            selectValue: supervise,
            faculty: faculty
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#ajaxResult").html(result);
        }
    })
});
```

When `#statement_button` from HTML markup returned from select dropdown is clicked

```
    $('#statement_button').click(function (e) {
    var student_statement = $("#student_statement").val();
    if (student_statement == '') {
        alert('Please enter your statement');
        return false;
    }
    var student = $("#student").val();
    var statement_button = $(this).attr("value");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: formsUrl,
        dataType: 'text',
        data:
        {
            student_statement: student_statement,
            student: studentusername,
            statement_button: statement_button
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#result").text(result);
            $("textarea#student_statement").val('');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You should delegate the button handling to a parent element (*the `.ajaxResult` seems a good fit*) that is always in the html so you do not need to include main.js in the ajax calls but can use it only once when the page loads for the first time.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Do you mind showing a snippet of what you're talking about?

Comment: can you post some code from inside main.js ?

Comment: snippet added to question

Comment: and do the `button` elements appear inside the `.ajaxResult` element ?

Comment: Yes. `button` is part of result returned at:  `success: function (result) { $("#ajaxResult").html(result);  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted it looks like you can just delegate the button handling to the `.ajaxResult` element which is always present in the html (*from the initial load*).

So just changing how you bind your button handlers should be enough

```
$("#students").on("change", function (e) {
```

to

```
$('.ajaxResult').on('change', '#students', function (e) {
```

---

```
$('#statement_button').click(function (e) {
```

to

```
$('.ajaxResult').on('click', '#statement_button', function (e) {
```

etc..

---

So the script with the above code is run once in the initial load of the page (*in a `$(document).ready(..)`*)